# TPL - How can I force TPL to use fixed # of threads? not less

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

How can I force TPL to use a fixed number of threads?  I know MaxDegreeOfParallelism can be used to set the upper limit, but I want the upper limit to equal the lower limit. Is this possible? How?

Because I know someone will ask =) yes, I'm sure I want to do this and yes its optimal for my scneario. =)

**EDIT**
The solution requires a custom Partitioner as well as the custom TaskScheduler http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/parallelextensions/thread/002ff888-6e13-4d7e-a234-1632e8a1f551

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create your own [TaskScheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx) if you really needed to, but using TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning is probably the best approach.

[How to: Create a Task Scheduler That Limits the Degree of Concurrency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351.aspx)

Comment: having trouble figuring out how to use LongRunning with Parallel.ForEach.  any suggestions?

Comment: The link you posed along with the link in my edit does the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using [`TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions.aspx) when creating the tasks? It's only a hint, but I believe it may help:

> Specifies that a task will be a long-running, coarse-grained operation. It provides a hint to the TaskScheduler that oversubscription may be warranted.

It's possible that that will oversubscribe it *beyond* MaxDegreeOfParallelism of course... you should probably try to find a resource which explains it in detail. How are you creating your tasks, by the way?

Comment: Hi Jon - good suggestion!  I'll dig deeper to see if it will oversubscribe.  I'm creating my tasks via Parallel.ForEach

Comment: posted comment to @BrandonAGr - having trouble figuring out how to use LongRunning with Parallel.ForEach. any suggestions?

Comment: @SFun28: Hmm - looks like you can't specify the task creation options there. Either create the tasks yourself, or consider writing your own task scheduler.